# IPFS url returning 404 and unable to get the asset

Tags: ipfs

I have an IPFS file which I found inside my NFT, I am unable to get the asset inside that URL, can someone help.

This is the URL:

```
ipfs://QmcFAs7GH9bh6Q11bLVwd5J2c5EefadeL5Q8bZBLnMYYSJ/464.json
```

and I tried from browser with this URL:

```
https://ipfs.io/QmcFAs7GH9bh6Q11bLVwd5J2c5EefadeL5Q8bZBLnMYYSJ/464.json
```

I just shows a loading screen and a `404` http status is returned.

Comment: ipfs:// URLs don't work in most browsers unless you install an extention. Download the Brave browser and try loading the first URL on it

Comment: Can you try the above URL, it doesnt work :(

Comment: Try this: `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcFAs7GH9bh6Q11bLVwd5J2c5EefadeL5Q8bZBLnMYYSJ/464.json`